# Laravel and Vuejs - how do I do with Translations

Tags: laravel, internationalization, vue.js

I have several select input in my Laravel app that require translation ( I manage several languages ).

Here is an example:

```
{!!  Form::select('gender', ['M'=> trans('core.male') ,
                            'F'=> trans('core.female') ,
                            'X'=> trans('core.mixt') , ],
                            null, ['class' => 'form-control',"v-model"=>"gender"]) !!}
```

So, basically, what I want to achieve is to be able to get the value of 'gender'.

Right now, I am able to get the id ('M', 'F', 'X')

Thing is I can't declare in my js because trans('core.male') won't work outsite of .blade.php files

So, I should make a web service and call it through AJAX, but is it really necessary???

Or I could setup each variable in a js variable inside my .blade.php but once more, it is not so nice if I have large lists.

I would prefer something lighter.

Any idea how to resolve it without generating fat code???

Comment: check vuejs [internationalization plugins](https://github.com/vuejs/awesome-vue#i18n)

Comment: Yes, I already checked it. Right now, it doesn't seem so easy, and I found very little resources about that. I will probably implement it, but later. Is it the only way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could give the element an `id` property, and then find the text of the selected option using javascript in a computed variable:

blade:

```
{!!  Form::select('gender', ['M'=> trans('core.male') ,
    'F'=> trans('core.female') ,
    'X'=> trans('core.mixt') , ],
    null, ['class' => 'form-control',"v-model"=>"gender","id"=>"gender"]) !!}
```

js:

```
....
computed:{
    selectedText: function () {

      this.gender = this.gender //this forces a re-compute when this.gender changes

      var sel = document.getElementById('#gender');

      if (sel.selectedIndex == -1)
        return null;

      return sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].text;
    }
}
....
```